# Symfony 3 use a second database in service

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony

I try to manage 2 databases in my symfony3 installation.
I want to have **two connections and not two managers** because the second database is just for loading external data and not to use with the orm.

my conf.yml

```
doctrine:
  dbal:
    default_connection: default
    connections:
      default:
          driver:   pdo_mysql
          host:     "%database_host%"
          port:     "%database_port%"
          dbname:   "%database_name%"
          user:     "%database_user%"
          password: "%database_password%"
          charset:  UTF8
      dbsync:
          driver:   pdo_mysql
          host:     "%database_sync_host%"
          port:     "%database_sync_port%"
          dbname:   "%database_sync_name%"
          user:     "%database_sync_user%"
          password: "%database_sync_password%"
          charset:  UTF8

  orm:
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
    naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
    auto_mapping: true
```

In a Controller i can use my second database for sql select with :

```
...->getManager()->getConnection('dbsync');
```

But I would like to use it in a service and I don't know how to use getConnection('dbsync') in this case ...
my service MajUsers.php

```
<?php
namespace EntBundle\Service;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use EntBundle\Entity\User\User;

class MajUsers {

  private $em;

  /**
   * @param EntityManager $em
   */
  public function __construct(EntityManager $em)
  {
    $this->em = $em;
  }

  public function runUpdate()
  {
     $conn = $this->em->getManager('dbsync')->getConnection('dbsync');
     $personnels_sync =  $conn->fetchAll("SELECT * FROM xxxxx WHERE etat = 1 AND login !='' ORDER BY xxx, yyyyLIMIT 10");
     ..... 
     .....
  }
}
```

my service.yml

```
ent.maj_users:
    class: EntBundle\Service\MajUsers
    arguments:
      - '@doctrine.orm.entity_manager'
```

I use the em for some repository in my code and it's working fine but the getConnection('dbsync') part is not working.
I suppose that I need to inject a container (doctrine?) in the __construct but I don't know witch one, all my test failed :c/

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATED:**

In your `__construct` type hint against `\Doctrine\DBAL\Connection` and define service like follows:

```
ent.maj_users:
    class: EntBundle\Service\MajUsers
    arguments:
      - '@doctrine.dbal.dbsync_connection'
```

Thanks to @Cerad for pointing out my mistake

---

**OLD:**

You can find it in docs [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html)

Basically, you should define service like this:

```
ent.maj_users:
    class: EntBundle\Service\MajUsers
    arguments:
      - '@doctrine.orm.dbsync_entity_manager'
```

Comment: Close but he only needs the connection so something like '@doctrine.dbal.dbsync_connection'

Comment: I already try this solution,Xymanek, but its for two managers and I need for two connections !

Comment: did you try doing what @Cerad suggested? I've saw that you type hinted EntityManager so I thought that you needed that service, my bad

Comment: I try to test Cerad solution but I don't know what to write in the __construct of the service ...

Comment: `\Doctrine\DBAL\Connection`

Comment: @lemairep Tick as answered please if your problem is fixed (general stackoverflow principle/rule)